# SQL Server 2016 LocalDb connection issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I created an application with a `.mdf` database file (version 13.00.4001).

If I run application on the same computer where I have compiled it, everything works great. But if I try to run it on a second computer with SQL Server LocalDb 2016 installed, it doesn't work and says that SQL Server cannot be found on computer.

What's the problem? I can't understand why.

And if I try to run application on a PC where there is installed SQL Server 2014 LocalDB and 2016 the log says

> cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

Really I can't understand why there are all these problems.

Code used to build connection string:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + 
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + 
@"\Dati.mdf; Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Well, you **cannot** use a database file from a SQL Server **2016** instance on an older version of SQL Server - so you **cannot** use that `.mdf` file with your SQL Server **2014** LocalDB - you must ensure that you're using the 2016 version of LocalDB (that's the second error you're getting)

Comment: I have installed 2016 and 2014 local db on the machine. 
And i have also tried with another machine where there was only 2016 installed and it doesn't work

Comment: You need to check your **connection strings** and make sure they point to a valid, installed, and running SQL Server LocalDB instance - and you **must ensure** that this is the **2016** version of LocalDB

Comment: Connection string is correct: "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Dati.mdf; Integrated Security=True

Comment: If you have two version of SQL Server installed, then you have two instances, and if LocalDB works the same as every other SQL Server DB then your connection string needs to reflect that . I suspect that (LocalDB) might not be correct in your connection string. Read this and see what your instances are called: https://www.davidbreyer.com/programming/2016/06/20/managing-sql-server-express-localdb-instances/. I will add the connection string to your question (in future please add it yourself)

Comment: I cannot solve this problem. I have found this issue only with SQL Server 2016. Seems that you have not installed sql server if you have installed only sql server 2016. 
With previous version there isn't any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Solved my problem by deleting existing MSSQLLocalDB instance and re-create it with this command line

> sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB

and

> sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB

and now all works great.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to move your code from one machine to another, but you aren't moving your database. This means you'll need to create a new database on the second machine and then get the new connection string, which will work on the second machine.

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312.aspx) for guidance on creating a database, but first install SQL Server Management Studio (look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)). You'll probably want to create some sort of configuration file to put the new connection string in. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) is guidance on that topic.

Comment: I create db from visual studio and when i compile it i move the complete out directory to another machine. Till now it has always work. I also have other application that works great

Answer (score 0):

Version 13.00.4001 corresponds to [SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/). When you are trying to restore / attach your database on another computer, make sure that not only the same version but also the same SP / CU is installed there.

To verify the version, you can connect to the instance and issue:

```
print @@version;
```

It will give you all the necessary information about build, edition, SP / CU, bitness, etc. of the instance in question.

Comment: I have installed this version in my secondary machine but it doesn't connect to this instance seems that i haven't installed anythink

Comment: If it's a LocalDB instance, you can list them and check their versions with console tool `sqllocaldb.exe`. For normal instances, you can find them in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Yes it's a localDb Instance I have tried with SqlLocalDb versions and the result is: 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (11.0.2318.0)
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8) 
But if i goes into the installed program list there is SqlLocalDb 2016 and if i try to re-install it told me that is already installed

Comment: And it returns another row with Windows Api Call "RegGetValueW" returned error code: 0.

Comment: You may have LocalDB 2016 installed, but do you have an instance of this version created? Try `sqllocaldb c "Inst2016" 13.0`, so that 2016 version will be used.

Comment: Ok command prompt told me that instance was succesfully created but when i try to open my application the result is always the same. 
Seems that no sql local db is installed. The error is that is not possible to create an automatic instance Local Database Runtime error

Comment: I have checked in windows event and the error is: Father instance version of local db is not valid: MSSQL12E.LOCALDB

Comment: @MirkoFogazzi Check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/1257bf26-6ab0-416d-bf26-34f128f42248